# Binding XAML properties to custom Object properties outside my DataContext (ViewModel) in wpf core

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying without success to bind some properties in XAML to the properties of some instantiated objects of a custom class I created.
What I have so far is (simplified):

In MainWindow.xaml:

```
<TextBox 
    Text="{Binding TEXTBOX.Text}"
    ...
<TextBox/>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = viewModel;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

In ViewModel.cs:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    GuiObject TEXTBOX = new GuiObject();
    TEXTBOX.Text = "starting text";
}
```

In my GuiObject.cs:

```
public class GuiObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text = String.Empty;
    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set => SetProperty(ref _text, value);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {

        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            field = newValue;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anybody please point me out how could I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
public ViewModel()
{
    GuiObject TEXTBOX = new GuiObject();
    TEXTBOX.Text = "starting text";
}
```

`TEXTBOX` here is a local variable. It is not accessible outside method. And binding needs public properties to work:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    TEXTBOX = new GuiObject { Text = "starting text" };
}

public GuiObject TEXTBOX { get; set; }
```

also: naming guideline for properties is `PascalCase` (`public GuiObject TextBox { get; set; }`)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately still does not prompt out on the GUI the "starting text"... seems as if the binding in XAML can not apply to my Object... I am still missing something?

Comment: can you check Visual Studio Output window for any messages about binding errors?

Comment: Showed 'System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TEXTBOX' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModel''' but my 'TEXTBOX' is an Object which has the property Text'...

Comment: `public GuiObject TEXTBOX { get; set; }` is defintely a property. If you changed it to `public GuiObject TextBox { get; set; }`, then modify xaml as well: `Text="{Binding Path=TextBox.Text}"`